# What status does the Roman Cathechism have nowadays?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism

I actually find the *Roman Catechism* much more interesting to read than the  *Catechism of the Catholic Church* (CCC) we have nowadays.

The CCC is actually less easy to read than the *Roman Catechism* for me.

The CCC was not written for people like me. It even frustrates me at time. The Roman Catechism does not frustrate me.

What status does the *Roman Catechism* have nowadays? Should we read it?

Answer (score 2):

Reading any catechism can be good, provided you understand the purpose of a catechism.

The purpose of a catechism is not to teach the faithful by reading it, but to assist the catecist (be he clergyman or layman) in his role of educating the faithful. This is not to say that laymen in a literate society cannot benefit from reading a catechism directly.

Most catechisms are written for a time, or a place. For isntance, the Baltimore Catechism was designed with Americans in mind. It was written for American catecists to teach Americans about the faith.

The *Catechism of the Catholic Church* is a universal catechism written for post-enlightenment Catholics. The Roman Catechism is also a universal catechism, written for reformation/renaissance era Catholics. If you find that you understand the Roman Catechism better than the *Catechism of the Catholic Church*, there is nothing wrong with you reading it.

Answer (score 2):

**What status does the *Roman Cathechism* have nowadays?**

Although not popular these days, it remains a valid educational tool still in use these days.

In fact, I personally know parishes that permit parents to use to use either system. The more traditional families use the *Roman Catechism*. A few parishes in my archdiocese do this very thing. Thus there is no issue for Catholics here on the subject matter.

If you feel more comfortable with the *Roman Catechism*, please continue to use it.

The *Roman Catechism* has not been abrogated, so you are free to use it.

Comment: Why then do so few recomend it? Is it hard to read for most people?

Comment: @harryjansson It seems a little option based, but I think most Catholics would look on it a an obsolete source, not in keeping with the modern Church. Not at all true.

Comment: It was written for Bishops and Priests but not for all people like the CCC. I thought the Roman Cathechism used a language that many people find difficult.